# Apache PHP - default upload file rights

Tags: php, apache, rights

I want the uploaded file rights set to rw-r--r-- by default but there are rw-r----- (read rights for others is missing...) .

1. The files upload via php. all umask already set to 022.

   root 0022 
   diradmin mysql majordomo webapps dovecot admin 0022 
   fw 0022
2. the base directory rights is 777

   [root@server1 library]# getfacl images 
   file: images 
   owner: fw 
   group: fw 
   user::rwx 
   group::rwx 
   other::rwx
3. touch command get me what i want (rw-r--r--).

but when upload file through website (php) the file rights was set to rw-r-----. I need read rights for other.

I struggled for this issue for a few days. I'm not sure whether directadmin involve to this issue. 
Anyone please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use chmod when you move the files after the upload to change all right

[the doc here](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.chmod.php)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Yeah sorry what's on a train and a little bit lazy I'll edit my post